# Startup and Exit events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, startup

I have created new WPF Project and what I would like to do is set something to do for an app on `Startup` and `Exit`.

In `App.xaml.cs`
I have added

```
public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    //code here
}
```

And

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    // code here
}
```

In `App.xaml` I have added to generated code:

```
<Application 
    ...
    Startup="Application_Startup"
    Exit="Application_Exit"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" >
```

What I am getting is an error (when I try to build the app):

> Error 1   'abc.App' does not contain a definition for
>   'Application_Startup' and no extension method 'Application_Startup'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'abc.App' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\abc\App.xaml 4   73  abc

I have tried to comment `StartupUri` or change it into `App.xaml` but without effect.

May anyone point me what I am doing wrong in this case ?

edit:
@S.Akbari
I have such a options like in this image.

http://i57.tinypic.com/212z4h3.png ( cannot upload here my picture because of lack of reputation)

I am reading about This `Navigate to Event Handler`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Application_Startup` and `Application_Exit` events in `App.xaml.cs` then in `App.xaml` right click on `Application_Startup` and select `Navigate to Event Handler`. Also do this for `Application_Exit` and then rebuild your project. build should succeeded.

[image]